# Laravel Blueprint complex unique

Tags: laravel, migration, blueprint

Let's say I have this following table which has an `enum` field and a foreign to some target table:

| id | genre enum('a','b','c') | is_primary | target_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | false | 1 |
| 2 | b | true | 1 |
| 3 | c | false | 1 |
| 4 | c | false | 1 |

Now I want to do some rules like following in my migration:

1. genre `a` with same `target_id` must be only one record
2. genre `b` with same `target_id` also must be only one record
3. the same `target_id`s must have only one record with `is_primary:true`
4. genre `c` can repeat in multiple records with same `target_id`

Is there any convenient way to do such thing with laravel Blueprint?

---

My migration:

```php
$table->id();
$table->uuid('uuid')->unique()->default(DB::raw('UUID()'));
$table->enum('type', ['RECHARGE', 'CONVERT', 'FREEZE']);
$table->foreignId('target_id')->references('id')->on('targets');
$table->boolean('is_primary')->default(false);
```

I want my datum having only one FREEZE and one RECHARGE record per each target, but the CONVERT type can be multiple. and also I need only one of these records to be `is_primary:true` per each target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with:

> 3. the same `target_id`s must have only one record with `is_primary:true`

You could achieve this by having a multi-column unique index for `target_id` and `is_primary` and setting `is_primary = NULL` for those rows where uniqueness is not required (i.e. those that are `false` in your example).

```
$table->boolean('is_primary')->nullable();
$table->unique(['is_primary', 'target_id']);
```

The other constellation

> 1. genre `a` with same `target_id` must be only one record
> 2. genre `b` with same `target_id` also must be only one record
> 3. genre `c` can repeat in multiple records with same `target_id`

would require a partial index, which is supported by some (e.g. Postgres), but not all DBMS (e.g. not MySQL).

cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_index,
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html